git - using gitconfig to switch repository host address
So right now I have some alias in my ~/.ssh/config:
Host github_company_a
    HostName github.com

Host github_company_b
    HostName github.com

and I use the alias directly: git clone git@github_company_a:<...>.
But recently I discovered the includeif entry from gitconfig.
Now I've my ~/.gitconfig like this:
[includeif "gitdir:~/Repos/company_a/"]
    path = .gitconfig_company_a
[includeif "gitdir:~/Repos/company_b/"]
    path = .gitconfig_company_b

For newo both .gitconfig_company_a and .gitconfig_company_b only have entries to configure the name and email:
[user]
    name = Foo
    email = bar@email.com

So now I am wondering: Would it be possible to use a gitconfig file to translate host names to another value?
Example: Let's say I'm at the ~/Repos/company_a/ and cloning something from github: git@github.com:<...>.
since we have a .gitconfig_company_a we could setup:
[user]
    name = Foo
    email = bar@email.com
[host github.com]
    replace = github_company_a

So when I located at the correct company folder I would NOT need to manually adjust the repository host address to the correct SSH Alias before cloning.
Thank you!

That's url.*.insteadOf, and it works backwards from your example:
[url "git@github_company_a:"]
    insteadOf = git@github.com:


Thank you! That really did the trick.
